# Request server url without explicit file name doesn't parse index.* files

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, php5

I've set up a new vServer with apache2, php5 and mysql.

When I enter my server url (e.g. example.org) in the browser it starts downloading the index.php instead of parsing it. But when I request a file (e.g. example.org/index.php) it parses it correctly.

This is in my php5.conf (snippet):

```
<FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

I also tried replacing the above lines with:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .phtml .php3 .php4 .php5 .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

but that didn't help either.

And this is in my httpd.conf:

```
AddHandler php5-script  .php
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

AddType text/html       .php

AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

I thought this is all I have to do to get it working... Hope you can help me out!

PS: I'm a "web server admin" novice. After any changes I restart apache2 and/or do a force-reload... nothing helps :(